# Does Tornado's XSRF protection work in a round-robin environment?

Tags: tornado, csrf

I intend to use [Tornado's XSRF protection](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-protection) in my web app. But I wonder: if I need to scale up to have a cluster of servers, will it still work - or will a request fail if the preceding request had gone to a different server?

Answer (score 1):

The XSRF token has no state on the server: it [is not checked](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/branch4.0/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.check_xsrf_cookie) against any known or stored value, other than the two instances of the token in the request:

1. The `_xsrf` cookie
2. Any one of:

   - The `X-Xsrftoken` header
   - The `X-Csrftoken` header
   - The `_xsrf` argument (e.g. `?_xsrf=...` for a `GET` request)

So it doesn't matter if the requests are not serviced by the same instance of the web server. This is probably true of other web servers too.